# How to run a macro if the current time matches any time value in a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of time values in cell Range D2 to D12. 
For example, D2 contains "12:30:00 PM" and D3 contains "1:30:00 PM". Some cells in the range may not contain any time so this is dynamic.

I would like to run a macro if current time (now) matches any of the time in the range.

Something like this:

if Now() = "Any time in the range" Then
run a macro
End if

I have been trying to apply the below. The code is from here [Scheduling macros](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/scheduling-macros-in-excel-with-application-ontime). But I also observed that the [Application.Wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.wait) function does a better job compared to using the Application.OnTime. I need help with applying the Application.Wait function to run a macro at specified times in a range.

```
Public ScheduledTime As Double
Public Const Interval = 5
Public Const MyProc = "MyCode"


Sub MyCode()
Debug.Print Now()
SetOnTime
End Sub

Sub SetOnTime()
ScheduledTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Interval)
Application.OnTime ScheduledTime, MyProc
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd work this totally different... I'd run a macro which will read all your cells with time and then schedule your main macro at these times. If the times change during the day, everytime your main macro is run, will run the first one deleting the previous schedulings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hunting and finding no perfect solution, I'm privileged to build one

```
Public ScheduledTime As Double
Public Const MyProc = "MyCode"



Sub MyCode()


'Macro to run
Debug.Print "Hello, this is a scheduled macro" & " " & Format(ScheduledTime, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
'Stop

End Sub

Sub SetOnTime()
Dim myArray As Variant, i As Long, numOfTimes As Long
Dim nextTime, newTime, waitTime

'Declare array
myArray = Range("D2:K5").Value
'Remove empty array values to get the exact number of values
'allow room for dynamic range
numOfTimes = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D2:K5"))


'Loop through array values
For i = 1 To numOfTimes

    'get the earliest time from the array
    nextTime = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(myArray, i)
    ScheduledTime = nextTime

    'Make it possible to change (add or subtract from) scheduled time
    waitTime = ScheduledTime + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)


    ' Show next time in Status bar
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Next Runtime: " & waitTime

    'Make program wait till waitTime and run code
    Application.Wait waitTime
    MyCode

Next i

End Sub
```